# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del campo seleccionado en Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Hace poco que estoy usando Xamarin.Forms y tengo esta duda en 2 campos diferentes:

1- Tengo un campo de texto que cuando me posiciono sobre él podemos ver que el puntero se marca de color rosa y el renglón del mismo también está en rosa. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de cambiarlo ya que no he encontrado ninguna.
[image: Texto]

2- También hay un campo en el cual uso un calendario para elegir una fecha, pero tiene el mismo problema, tiene el color de fondo en rosa.
[image: Calendario]

Tengo que usar una cierta gama de colores para hacer esta App y el rosa no está dentro de esa gama, lo raro es que estos colores ya aparecen por defecto y no se por que... dejo aquí el código fuente del xaml para que puedan ver si hay algo que me falte o que esté haciendo mal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TECAndroid.NuevoParteTecnico">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="12">
            <Label Text="Nuevo Parte Tecnico" />
            <Button x:Name="btnScan" Text="Leer Codigo QR" BackgroundColor="#28679D" TextColor="White" Clicked="BtnScan_Clicked"></Button>
            <Entry x:Name="txtBarcode" Placeholder="Texto del QR"/>

            <Picker x:Name="ddlClientes" SelectedIndex="{Binding Clientes}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Title="Cliente" SelectedItem="--Seleccione un Cliente--">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>--Seleccione un Cliente--</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
            <Label x:Name="lblFechaIngreso" Text="Fecha de Ingreso" FontSize="Large"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="FechaIngreso" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" DateSelected="FechaIngreso_Selected" />

            <Label x:Name="lblProducto" Text="Producto" FontSize="Large"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblFalla" Text="Falla" FontSize="Large"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblEstado" Text="Estado" FontSize="Large"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: Verifica si en la carpeta Resources aparece un archivo llamado colors.xml y dime si esta.

Comment: Hola Einer... No, no está

Comment: Disculpa, la ruta es Resources/values/colors.xml

Comment: Sisi, busque dentro de toda la carpeta Resources pero no está ese archivo... el que si se encuentra es styles.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu carpeta Resources/values hay un archivo llamado styles.xml, el contenido de este archivo es XML dentro de un elemento style hay un elemento llamado **colorAccent** este es el color de acento que usará tu aplicación, pon el valor RGB que tu quieras y se vera reflejado en lo elementos gráficos que tu mencionas.

Algo como lo siguiente:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
<item name="colorAccent">#fbae42</item>
```

Saludos !

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a Einer pude encontrar la solución al problema.

Dentro del proyecto android en la carpeta Resources/Values/ hay un archivo llamado styles.xml cuyo contenido es el siguiente...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Lo unico que hay que hacer es cambiar las sentencias

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
```

por

```
<item name="colorAccent">#EF9D37</item>
```

En este caso yo lo cambie a amarillo, pero eso depende de cada uno...